# Accessing a variable from outside a function - Javascript, API, XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, api, get

Just wanting to access the 'data' variable from this XMLHttpRequest function. Need to use the data in my 'App' react component which is below.

I have tried making the 'let data' global?
But just need to be able to access it outside of the function where the 'outside' console.log is. Currently, it shows undefined.

So asking how to make my data be accessed by my react component 'App'.

Sorry, I am new to using this function to get API data.

Thank you for the help, and if you need any more information please ask!

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)

let data

request.onload = function () {
   let data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach((movie) => {
      console.log(movie.title)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

console.log(data,"outside")

request.send()



    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
          
          };
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <DateRangePickerWrapper value={this.state.child1}/> 
                </>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61285073/6482248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using class programming on your react aplication, so you must do somenthing
like this

```
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: []}

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
            .then(response =>{
                this.setState({data: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        axios.get("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
            .then(response =>{
                this.setState({data: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    
    render() {

       
        
        return (
            <div>
                {data.map(data=> (

                //logic to render the api's data
                
                ))}
                

                    
                
            </div>

            
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how to do it**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [readData, writeData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => writeData(json));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div>title: {readData.title}</div>
      <div>completed: {String(readData.completed)}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-resonance-pq3pl?file=/src/App.js)

I struggled with this exact question when I was first dealing with async code.

If you have async code in React the formula is simple. Have some state, when the async code runs, update the state and the changes should be reflected in your jsx.